# How to re-assign static IP address from one cluster to another in the google container engine

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, static-ip-address

I setup cluster via gcloud container engine, where I have deployed my pods with nodejs server running on them. I am using LoadBalancer service and static IP for routing the traffic across these instances. Everything works perfectly, but I forget to specify write/read permission for google storage api, and my server cannot save files to the bucket storage.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837531/changing-permissions-of-google-container-engine-cluster) answer there is no way I can change permissions (scopes) for cluster after it was created. So I created a new cluster with correct permissions and re-deployed my containers. I would like to re-use the static IP, I have received from google, tell loadBalancer to use existing IP and remove old cluster. How to do that? I really don't want to change DNS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `type: LoadBalancer` style service then you can use the `loadBalancerIP` field on the service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.10.10.10
  ...
```

If you are using an `Ingress` you can use an annotation on Google Cloud to set the IP address. Here you use the IP address name in Google Cloud rather than the IP address itself.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: myingress
 annotations:
   "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name": my-ip-name
spec:
  ...
```