# Can't deploy marketplace object on GKE

Tags: permissions, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a running Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform.

I want to deploy a `postgres` image to my cluster.

When selecting the image and my cluster, I get the error:

`insufficient OAuth scope`

I have been reading about it for a few hours now and couldn't get it to work.

I managed to set the `scope` of the `vm` to allow APIs:

```
Cloud API access scopes
Allow full access to all Cloud APIs
```

But from the GKE cluster details, I see that everything is disabled except the `stackdriver`.

Why is it so difficult to deploy an image or to change the scope?

How can I modify the cluster permissions without deleting and recreating it?

Comment: Are you using the GCP admin user to deploy these?

Comment: yes, it seems like the permission for the api is blocked

Comment: Check with GCP support, not sure what else there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to delete and recreate the cluster because there is no direct way to modify the scopes of a cluster. However, there is a workaround. Create a new node pool with the correct scopes and make sure to delete any of the old node pools. The cluster scopes will change to reflect the new node pool.

More details found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134385/is-it-necessary-to-recreate-a-google-container-engine-cluster-to-modify-api-perm)