# GCS read write access from the GKE Pod without credentials/auth

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-storage

We created the GKE cluster with the **public** endpoint. The **service account** of the GKE **cluster** and **Node pool** has the following roles.

```
"roles/compute.admin",
"roles/compute.viewer",
"roles/compute.securityAdmin",
"roles/iam.serviceAccountUser",
"roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin",
"roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin",
"roles/container.admin",
"roles/artifactregistry.admin",
"roles/storage.admin"
```

The node pool of the GKE cluster has the following **OAuth scopes**

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write",
```

The **private** GCS bucket has the same service account as the principal, with the **storage admin** role.

When we try to read/write in this bucket from a GKE POD, we get the below error.

```
# Read
AccessDeniedException: 403 Caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket

# Write
AccessDeniedException: 403 Caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object
```

We also checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497002/gcs-write-access-from-inside-a-gke-pod) but the solution was credential oriented and couldn't help us. **We would like to read/write without maintaining the SA auth key or any sort of credentials**.

Please guide what is missing here.

---

**UPDATE**: as per the suggestion by @boredabdel we checked and found that `workload identity` was already enabled on the GKE cluster as well as NodePool. We are using this [module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/kubernetes-engine/google/latest/submodules/beta-private-cluster) to create our cluster where it is already enabled by default. Still, we are facing connectivity issues.

**Cluster**
Security:

[image]

**NodePool**
Security:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to use the Node Service Account to authenticate to GCS. You need to passe the Service Account Key to the app you are calling the API from as described in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically)

If you want Keyless authentication, my advice is to use [Workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity)

Comment: Hi, @boredabdel thank you for your suggestion. It looks like WI is already enabled by default in our cluster. I have updated the question with the relevant info. Please check and suggest.

Comment: Enabled is not enough. You have to configure both your workload and IAM for Workload Identity to work. You can check this documentation https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to

Comment: Hey, @boredabdel thanks for your help. We were able to configure the workload identity and access GCS without keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is for all who are looking for an answer to implement this solution via terraform. Please refer below:

###### Create a Kubernetes service account with annotation

```
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "service_account" {
  manifest = {
    "apiVersion" = "v1"
    "kind"       = "ServiceAccount"
    "metadata" = {
      "name"      = "KSA_NAME"
      "namespace" = "NAME"
      "annotations" = {
        "iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account" = "GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }
    }
    "automountServiceAccountToken" = true
  }
}
```

###### Create an IAM policy binding to allow the Kubernetes service account to act as the IAM service account.

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "service-account-iam" {
  service_account_id = "projects/PROJECT_ID/serviceAccounts/GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  role               = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"
  members            = [
    "serviceAccount:${var.project_id}.svc.id.goog[NAMESPACE/KSA-NAME]",
  ]
}
```

###### Add service account to the deployment/statefulset manifest like this

```
spec:
  serviceAccount: KSA-NAME
  containers:
```

**NOTE**:

1. GSA_PROJECT and PROJECT_ID are the same if you are using the same project for all objects.
2. K8s service account is created via `resource "kubernetes_manifest"` method because there is an open [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/issues/1724) for it to create via `resource "kubernetes_service_account"` method where it is throwing an error stating. *`Waiting for default secret of "NAMESPACE/KSA_NAME" to appear`*

Comment: looks good thanks for sharing, and yes right default secret are not getting generated for SA from 1.24 version